# Why do i require to select my branch master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In my sourcetree i appear to be asked all the tiem to select a branch i didnt normally have to do this but we moved our repos to a new account and now its forcing it to ask each time i do a pull[image]

And also where there is normally a badge number indictating about many pulls im behind on the tool bar it is not showing at present for my solutions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your local branch does not know which branch it is tracking from the remote `vault`.

Check that with the output of `git branch -avv`

Make sure your branch is tracking one from vault

```
git branch -u Vaultx/abranch abranch
```

Then check in the SourceTree GUI if a pull still ask you for a branch.

Comment: Hi I obv hid my .git path for security  but it def is tracking the vault x git which iis odd like

Comment: @rogue39ni OK. what is the output of `git branch -avv`?

Comment: * master                791425c Prepare project to "Publish"
  remotes/Vaultx/master b04fdb5 Correct introducer displaying on edit

Comment: So it looks like `master` does track `VaultX` `master`. What is the output of `git remote -v`? Do you have a remote named `Vaultx`? (it is case sensitive)

Comment: I no its not nessary but its nice to have picese of mind without having to select it all the time

Comment: OK. What is the output of `git remote -v`? Do you have a remote named `Vaultx`?

Comment: Yes I do im committing to it its just the badges on the big icons missing the badges to the left of the screen are there notifiying me how many i am behind etc.

Comment: it is correct for the paths i dont want to publish results as would mean full access to my git repo

Comment: Sure. On what os are you? Windows? Linux? What version of Git and of Source tree are you using?

Comment: Windows ten  Source Tree version 1.9.6.1 i no about the windows tne issue affecting repos but this was working before we moved and restructured our repos

Comment: All I can think of is that your Source tree is displaying vaultx, not Vaultx. That seems strange considering the name of a remote is case sensitive